# Getting journald to send email on certain events

Tags: linux, syslog, systemd, journald

I found these solutions for syslogd that send emails on certain events like local0.crit  or local1.err

[How can I make syslogd email certain log messages to me?](https://serverfault.com/questions/32360/how-can-i-make-syslogd-email-certain-log-messages-to-me)
http://www.johnandcailin.com/blog/john/how-setup-real-time-email-notification-critical-syslog-events

However my system is running on systemd and thus using journal for syslog purposes. How can I implement email based on events without having a cron running that checks all logs each 5 minutes and sends the logs to an address or similar?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no such functionality in journald and I don't think it will ever be implemented.

Instead, you may implement your own journal log watcher using the [python API to read the journal](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/python-systemd/journal.html#accessing-the-journal).