# Send mail when ClamAV detects a threat using systemd

Tags: systemd, syslog, clamav

Most of the guides for ClamAV discuss integration with syslog, and it is possible to [configure syslog to send a message on certain logs](https://serverfault.com/q/32360/50236). But, my system is running systemd, with no active `syslog.service`. How could I configure ClamAV to send a message on a threat detection in this setup?

Comment: What guide? I haven't seen anything that requires syslog. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I see that it doesn't require syslog. But, even the comments in `clamd.conf` provide a guide on integration with syslog. However, the question about sending me a message when the service detects a threat still remains.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a configuration setting within ClamAV itself, but [I did find a script I could configure with `cron`](https://github.com/crylium/clamav-daily) (and [an article that explains it](https://www.lisenet.com/2014/automate-clamav-to-perform-daily-system-scan-and-send-email-notifications-on-linux/)):

```
#!/bin/bash
# written by Tomas Nevar (tomas@lisenet.com)
# 17/01/2014 (dd/mm/yy)
# copyleft free software
#
LOGFILE="/var/log/clamav/clamav-$(date +'%Y-%m-%d').log";
HOST="$(hostname --long)";
EMAIL_MSG="Please see the log file attached.";
EMAIL_FROM="clamav-daily@"$HOST"";
EMAIL_TO="admin@example.com";
DIRTOSCAN="/home";

# Check for mail installation
type mail >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "I require mail but it's not installed. Aborting."; exit 1; };

# Update ClamAV database
echo "Looking for ClamAV database updates...";
freshclam --quiet;

TODAY=$(date +%u);

if [ "$TODAY" == "6" ];then
    echo "Starting a full weekend scan.";
    # be nice to others while scanning the entire root
    nice -n5 clamscan -ri / --exclude-dir=/sys/ &>"$LOGFILE";
else
    DIRSIZE=$(du -sh "$DIRTOSCAN"  2>/dev/null|cut -f1);
    echo -e "Starting a daily scan of "$DIRTOSCAN" directory.\nAmount of data to be scanned is "$DIRSIZE".";
    clamscan -ri "$DIRTOSCAN" &>"$LOGFILE";
fi

# get the value of "Infected lines"
MALWARE=$(tail "$LOGFILE"|grep Infected|cut -d" " -f3);

# if the value is not equal to zero, send an email with the log file attached
if [ "$MALWARE" -ne "0" ]; then
    echo "$EMAIL_MSG"|mail -a "$LOGFILE" -s "ClamAV: Malware Found" -r "$EMAIL_FROM" "$EMAIL_TO";
fi

echo "The script has finished.";
exit 0;
```

Note that this script uses `mailx`, so it would take slight re-working to make this script work with another mail agent, like `sendmail`.